# Simple asymptotic combinatorics - how many words are there in a certain weight category?

Tags: co.combinatorics, formal-languages

Given the set of all binary strings of length n, I am looking at the "middle" of these strings, weight-wise.

Namely, I am trying to calculate how many words are there whose weight is between n/2 - sqrt(n) and n/2 + sqrt(n).

Clearly this term can also be described as a sum of binomial coefficients, but I don't know how to simplify it. I am less interested in the exact outcome (Although it would be great if I could get it), and more interested in the asymptotical lower bound. (Is this about Omega(2^n)? Omega(2^sqrt(n))? Something else?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation

Comment: Follow the link Steve gives.  This is not a research level question and is therefore inappropriate for this site.  You'll get help at http://math.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

To spell out the hint a bit more explicitly - the mean number of 1s in a random binary string of length $n$ is $n/2$, and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{n}/2$.  So you're looking for the number of such words which have their number of 1s within two standard deviations of the mean.